# Having a variable variable inside a function

Tags: python, function, variables

I would like to insert the input of a function (lets call it label) into the name of global variable so it is a unique variable based on the input. In an example script this would be something like:

```
#Script/function 1 - when a file is deleted in a folder it triggers an event 
# that runs function on_deleted():

on_deleted()
def on_deleted(event):
    if "partoffilename1" in list_of_files:
        do_this(label1)
    elif "partoffilename2" in list_of_files:
        do_this(label2)
```

```
#Script/function 2 - for every label input it has its own variable that has some
# calculations/iterations on a 'long' list of globals (!). So for each label it should 
# pick its unique global, but also some globals that span across the other labels.

def do_this(label):
   #Import globals here, which mostly all the variabeles below
   label_min += -1
   label_done = abs(label_min)
   start_time_label = datime.now()
   #and then around 180 more lines of code with each a unique variable for the label
```

The trick which I can't figure out is how to have the variables be variable based on the input of the second function *do_this()* which is a label. Currently I had just copy pasted it for one instance and renamed all the variables based on the label.... so a ugly and long code that is hard to maintain.

I looked into using a `dict` in the second function, but then I still need to address each variable individually to assign it a value.
The other option is probably a `class`, but I have a long list of variables within one class and I don't know how to avoid the following:

```
class label:
   class_variable_1 = "bla1"
   class_variable_2 = "bla2"
   
   def __init__(self, param1, param2, ....., param100):
      self.instance_var1 = param1
      self.instance_var2 = param2
      ....
      self.instance_var100 = param100
```

So maybe the question should be, is there a smart solution to avoid a long list of inputs/params for the `def __init__` within a class? Or am I bound to that?

Comment: Any time you find yourself need dynamic variables names, you should be using a list or dictionary.

Comment: How about this, `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):`

Comment: Never worked with those, guess back to the drawing board/tutorials for a second, thanks @JasonYang for the response